# cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'LPSTR'

Tags: c++, windows

As I clould not pass LPCSTR from one function to another (Data get changed) I tried passing it as a string.

But later I need to again convert it back to LPSTR. While trying the conversion I am getting the above error:

> cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'LPSTR'

How can I resolve this?

Comment: How are trying the conversion?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

That's just because you should use [`std::string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method.

But this involves `const_cast` in given case because `const char *` returned by `c_str()` can not be assigned to a non-constant `LPSTR`.

```
std::string str = "something";
LPSTR s = const_cast<char *>(str.c_str());
```

But you must be sure that lifetime of `str` will be longer that that of `LPTSTR` variable.

Another mention, if code compiles as Unicode-conformant, then types `LPTSTR` and `std::string` are incompatible. You should use `std::wstring` instead.

**Important note:** If you pass the resulting pointer `s` from above to a function which tries to modify the data it is pointing to this will result in undefined behaviour. The only way to properly deal with it is to duplicate the string into a non-const buffer (e.g. via `strdup`)

Comment: @Keynslug, Eventually Solved my problem. But why is this( const_cast:) horrible

Comment: The last paragraph is wrong too, LPSTR is *always* char*, even in a Unicode build.  You're talking about LPTSTR.

Comment: @ereOn Mentioned about `const_cast` while writing answer but removed mention somewhy. But why `const_cast<char *>(str.c_str())` is undefined behavior? Is that right because we cannot guarantee that lifetime of `str` will be longer that that of `LPTSTR` variable?

Comment: You should fix the const_cast<> as well.  Flip your answer to CW if you don't like the downvotes.

Comment: @Keynslug: `c_str()` gives something `const`. Removing the `const` qualifier supposes that you make an assumption about the underlying implementation of `c_str()` and know for sure that it is not `const`. Even if this was true for your compiler, modifying the returned value won't modify the `std::string` itself, so what's the point ?

Comment: Note you don't need const_cast for LPCSTR, relevant since this q is the target of a few dupes.

Answer (score 8):

If you need an `LPSTR`, that means the string will/may be modified. `std::string::c_str()` returns a `const` pointer, and you can't just `const_cast` it away and hope all is good in the world, because it isn't. The string may be changed in all sorts of nasty ways, and your original `std::string` will be oblivious to all of them.

Try this instead:

```
// myFunction takes an LPSTR
std::string cppString = "something";
LPSTR cString = strdup( cppString.c_str() );
try {
   myFunction( cString );
   cppString = cString;
} catch(...) {
   free( cString );
}
```

Wrap the string in a smart pointer and get rid of the `try...catch` for bonus points (don't forget the custom deleter).

Answer (score 1):

There is a function on [std::string c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) .  However I doubt that you could not use a std::string in your case.

Comment: If the OP is calling a Win32 API, he can't use `std::string` directly.

Comment: I read it as two functions he wrote.  Since you can't pass a std::string into any windows api function with out conversion anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running `somestringvariablename.c_str()`?
That should work.

Answer (score 0):

An LPSTR can be substituted with by using a TCHAR (i.e. found in tchar.h). So if you have a std::string, you can use the method std::string::c_str().

Answer (score 0):

If the function, you are calling does not write to string, but only reads it, then you can simply use string::c_str method. If it is going to write something, then you probably should ensure that your string has enough space by calling string::reserve().