# Invalid argument deleting file

Tags: c++, file

I have made this very simpel program and all it needs to do is deleting a file

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{

string x = "C:\Users\dino\Documents\profiles\fil.txt";
if(remove(x.c_str()) != 0)
    {
        perror("Error deleting ");
    }
return 0;

}
```

But the perror gives me `Invalid argument`

Can't i choose the directory of the file I want to delete? if not, is there another way i can?

Comment: You do know what backslashes in a string literal does?

Comment: You need to `#include <stdio.h>` for `perror`, or `#include <cstdio>` for `std::perror`. Also, escape the \, or replace by `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your string. . .

```
string x = "C:\\Users\\dino\\Documents\\profiles\\fil.txt";
```

Comment: oh yea my bad, but lets say i have a function that returns the directory to  documents how can i then escape my string?

Comment: depends on what that function returns? If you are getting a list of files, with paths, using a system call, these will probably already be escaped correctly. You would need to elaborate. . . .

Comment: I use `SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_PERSONAL, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, my_documents);`

Comment: Then you would do this
PathAppend(szPath, TEXT("New Doc.txt")); where szPath is the path you got from SHGetFolderPath

Comment: that gives me an error
`error: C2664: 'PathAppendA' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'LPSTR'`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906515/cannot-convert-from-stdstring-to-lpstr