# CreateProcess with std::string

Tags: c++

I am trying to CreateProcess with std::string, I have searched almost everywhere to figure out how to convert a std::string to LPSTR

I am new to C++

I'm making a GUI, and when I click a button, I want to launch a program based on the path that I input, and the the 32-bit or 64-bit check box I put.

For the client directory I change System::String ^ to std::string

```
std::string path = this->getClientDirectory(); // Get the directory that the user has set

// Get the EXE bit that the user has ticked.
std::string exe;
if (this->isClient32Ticked)
    exe = "client_x32.exe";
else
    exe = "client_x64.exe";

//add the exe name to the end of the string.
path.append("\\");
path.append(exe);

CreateProcess(NULL, path, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Try path:c_str()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'LPSTR'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906515/cannot-convert-from-stdstring-to-lpstr)

Comment: Thanks @TheKitchenSink

Answer (score 3):

You either need to use the `c_str` method with `CreateProcessA`...

```
CreateProcessA(NULL, path.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Or make `path` a `std::wstring` and use `data` with `CreateProcess` (or `CreateProcessW`), and live in a distant-enough future that `std::basic_string::data` has a non-`const` version (this should happen with C++17, but MSVC hasn't caught up to it yet).

```
CreateProcessW(NULL, path.data(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

The W version of CreateProcess may modify the command parameter in-place, meaning that you shouldn't pass a "read-only" version of it. Strangely enough, the A version doesn't.

Comment: `data()` is `const` mate

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, that's probably the first time I'm blamed for MSVC's (hopefully temporary) non-compliance. Fortunately, the other half of the answer still stands.

Comment: The A version internally converts the string and then calls the W version. That conversion copies the string to a  temporary buffer so it's no surprise that the input is const

Answer (score 2):

LPSTR stands for Long Pointer STRing. It is equivalent to char[] or char*.

It is possible to get the char buffer from a std::string using the c_str() method. But that buffer will be const.

What you must do here is to allocate a non-const buffer of char and copy the std::string const-char buffer into it.

```
char* path = new char[exe.size() + 1] = {'\0'};   //Create the non-const char buffer initialized with zero characters
strncpy(path, exe.c_str(), exe.size());           //Copy the content from exe to path
CreateProcess(NULL, path, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
delete path[];
```

I also see something that might cause you issues in your post:

The fact that you mention converting System::String^ to std::string. Sometimes this will work and sometimes it will not. The reason is the way .NET stores string compared to the STL. I won't go into details about why here since this is not your question. When passing a managed string to a native string, you should always marshal it first using:

```
System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(System::String^)
```

You don't need to do anything special when passing the string from native to managed.

Comment: The point was to illustrate the concept for the data storage of the char buffer. The address of the first element of the array is the pointer.